# Что означает фраза данные передаются поверх протокола?

Tags: http, ssl, https, tls, протоколы

Часто при описании протоколов передачи данных присутствует слово "поверх". Что это означает? Например, данные в протоколе HTTPS передаются поверх криптографических протоколов SSL или TLS? - поверх это где? как это понять?

Answer (score 2):

Применить такую формулировку можно тогда, когда нижний по уровню протокол поддерживает передачу данных требуемую верхним протоколом.

Например, TLS требует, что бы протокол поверх которого он будет работать поддерживал передачу любых бинарных данных с контролем отправки/приема и четкой последовательностью данных. Такое свойство имеет сетевой протокол TCP, поэтому TLS может работать поверх TCP.

UDP не имеет таких свойств, поэтому для UPD придумали свою версию TLS, которая называется DTLS.

Если мы посмотрим с другой стороны, TLS так же поддерживает передачу любых бинарных данных с контролем целостности данных. Это значит мы можем запустить другой протокол поверх TLS, который требует этого. Например FTP, HTTP. Можно даже сделать TLS поверх TLS (сколько угодно раз).

Если описать другими словами, это значит, что протокол верхнего уровня может работать прозрачно поверх протокола нижнего уровня. Имеется ввиду, протокол верхнего уровня ничего не знает о нижнем протоколе, и не требует никаких модификаций.